# Snake game: How to increase the length of a snake body based on the amount of food eaten?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to recreate the snake game where the snake eats food and the body increases by 1 unit. However I've tried multiple times to increase the length of the body, but nothing has been working the way I want it to. I tried to create another breed of turtles called "tails" and hatch it behind the snake. But since I'm using ticks, the tails spawn really quickly and they don't create a snake-like effect. Instead, the tails bunch together on one patch behind the snake.

I've tried coloring the patches the snake was on but I didn't know how to only color a certain amount of patches based on the food eaten and add onto it gradually. So now, I tried using the breed tails, but it doesn't create a snake shape.

Here's my code:

```
breed [snakes snake]
breed [foods food]
breed [tails tail]
tails-own [age]

to game2-setup

  create-snakes 1 [
  set shape "snake"
  set color green
  ]

create-foods 10 [
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
if [pcolor] of patch-here != black [move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 
black]]
set shape "plant"
set color red]
end

to game2-go

;moves the snake
ask snakes [
if ticks mod 350 = 0 [fd 1]
]

;to kill snake if it bumps into a wall/itself
ask snakes
[if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 != black [
user-message "Game over" ]
]

 ;if the snake and food is on the same patch the food is eaten
 ask patches [ if any? snakes-here and any? foods-here
 [ask foods-here [die]
 set points points + 1
 set energy energy + 1
 ]]

 ;grows the tail of the turtle based on the amount of food eaten
 ask tails
 [set age age + 1
 if age = 10 [die]
 ]

 ;regrows the food
 if count foods < 10
 [create-foods 1
 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor
 if [pcolor] of patch-here != black [move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 
 black]]
 set shape "plant"
 set color red]
 ]
 tick
 end
```

I expect the snake tails to trail after the snakehead and increase base on the amount of food eaten.

Comment: There's alot of work that needs to be done between what you want and what you have. Seems the best approach would be to simulate that your snake has already eaten 5 plants. If that's the case, how does the snake move with all 5 pieces? Then, if the snake eats a plant, just spawn a segment where the tail used to be. You'll probably want to keep track of the tail of the snake for this purpose and the previous xcor/ycor of the tail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One convenient approach to a problem like this is to use links to connect the segments forming the snake.

The code below should help you get started. I won't walk you through the whole thing, but the general approach is to connect each "tail" segment to the segment ahead using directed links.

When adding a new tail segment, we recursively look for a segment that doesn't yet have an "in" link, hatch a new tail segment from there, and connect it to its parent.

When moving, each tail segment faces the segment it is connected to and moves within one patch of it. Notice how we use `foreach sort tails` instead of just `ask tails` to make sure that the segments are moved in their order of creation.

```
breed [snakes snake]
breed [tails tail]
breed [foods food]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-snakes 1 [ set color green ]
  ask n-of 10 patches [ sprout-foods 1 [ set shape "plant" ] ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask snakes [
    right random 45
    left random 45
    forward 1
    if any? foods-here [
      ask one-of foods-here [ die ]
      add-tail
    ]
  ]
  foreach sort tails [ t ->
    ask t [
      let segment-ahead one-of out-link-neighbors
      face segment-ahead
      forward max list 0 (distance segment-ahead - 1)
    ]
  ]
  tick
end

to add-tail
  ifelse any? in-link-neighbors [
    ask one-of in-link-neighbors [ add-tail ]
  ] [
    hatch-tails 1 [ create-link-to myself ]
  ]
end
```